# Manually start a turnbasedgame multiplayer, Android

Tags: android, google-play-services

**Background:**
I have a working game where user can start matches through Google's standard interface. 2-4 players works fine.

I have created a custom interface where players can connect as "Friends" and from that interface start matches.

**Issue:**
When I manually calling Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.createMatch for 2 players, it works most of the time.
Function is called in the end of onSignInSucceeded.
(I would prefere to call this in onActivityResult (as the default interface does) but then I'm not connected...)

When I call it for 3-4 players, it never works.
The callback returns GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_OPERATION_FAILED.

**Observation** It seems also to differ depending on the persons Goolge IDs, some starts with G follows by numbers and some only have the numbers (not starting with G).

```
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
....
TurnBasedMatchConfig tbmc = TurnBasedMatchConfig.builder().addInvitedPlayers(myinvitees).setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria).build();

Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.createMatch(getApiClient(), tbmc).setResultCallback( new ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.InitiateMatchResult>() {
@Override
public void onResult(TurnBasedMultiplayer.InitiateMatchResult result) {
    processResult(result);
}
});
```

Where myinvitees is an ArrayList with GoogleIDs of my opponents

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Edit:
Did some smaller changes but in general I have the same behavior.
Some times the games starting (with up to 4 players) but it seems to prefer the IDs starting with "G"...

Comment: Could it be that onSignInSucceeded is not equal to actually being connected to the internet? any ideas where I should call the start match function?

Comment: [STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_OPERATION_FAILED](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesStatusCodes#STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_OPERATION_FAILED) means A network error occurred while attempting to perform an operation that requires netwok.
Did all 4 players have stable network connection?

Comment: This is when the match is created. so no other player is contacted.
There is stable connection. this only occurs when I'm starting it manually. Through Google interface it always works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after moving the check if a request for starting a match exist to onSignInSucceeded(), it seems that Google have done something with the GoogleID I'm pulling from the players.
Newer users with ID that startas with G(and a lot of numbers) seems to work but not a mix of old once (that does not start with G) and the new.